# Saving Image into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I insert an image into a SQL Server database, if the image is null, then it inserts a `0x` value into the database image column.

When I retrieve the image with 0x hex value, I get an error:

> Parameter is not valid

```
string strsql = "SELECT [ID],PIC_Name FROM [HRMS].[dbo].[Employee_PC] where Id = '" + mFieldValue1 + "'";   
myconn = new OleDbConnection(clsConnections.conString);
myconn.Open();

cmd = new OleDbCommand(strsql, myconn);
OleDbDataReader dr = null;

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    if ((byte[])dr[1]  == null )
    //if (picData == null) 
    {
      pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
    else
    {
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dr[1]);
      ms.Position = 0;
      pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: check if the value returned from the database is not 0x (or DBNull)

Comment: You *can* save images in your DB, but I strongly suggest that you only save references to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

`dr[1]` won't be `null`, so neither will `(byte[])dr[1]`. You want to check the first byte *in* that array.

```
byte[] picData = (byte[])dr[1];

if (picData[0] == 0)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
else
{
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picData);
  ms.Position = 0;
  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
}
```